# Highlighting on XFCE4-terminal no longer persistent when upgrading to Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: xfce, xfce4-terminal

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 23.04 to 23.10 and have observed that highlighted text (using left-mouse button, swipe) no longer remains highlighted once the mouse button is released.

Other terminal emulators, such as the venerable xterm and KDE konsole, still persist the highlighting after the button is released.  It is obviously useful to be able to check that you've highlighted what you think you've highlighted before pasting into another window, an editor, or what not.

I searched Preferences and didn't see anything that leaped out at me as an obvious fix.

This worked up to the point I upgraded the OS this morning.

Any clues will be greatly appreciated.